# How to pass NULL value in fetch to backend for update?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

In my React Native 0.66 app, here is the `fetch` used to update backend db:

```js
let update = {
  status:"BidPlaced",
  buyer_id:Null, //<<==how to pass NULL for update?
  buy_date:NULL,  //<<==how to pass NULL for update?
};


res = await fetch(url, {. 
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',   
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(update), 
});
```

there is a need to pass `NULL` value in `fetch` to back end (nodejs + sequelize/postgres) for update. I notice if empty string is used `buyer_id: , buy_date:` , then `JSON.stringify` will omit them since there is no value provided for both `buyer_id` and `buy_date`. What is the right way to send `NULL` in `fetch` to update back end which is nodejs and sequelize/postgres?

Comment: Spell it `null`. This is the only null value that can be represented in JSON.

Comment: I never understood JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `null` not `NULL` or `Null`

Answer (score 0):

If you send `null` to a WebApi, the backend may consider it as `"null"` which is a string.

If the backend if implemented by .NetCore you can send an empty string `""` instead of `null`.